# Android Emulator Won't Let Me Mount And Copy A File To It

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to follow the tutorial :

http://borkweb.com/story/setting-etchosts-on-an-android-emulator-using-a-mac

But when I type:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 remount
```

All I get is `remount of /system failed: Read-only file system`

So then I try this..

```
MAC-M-N20B:~ user$ adb shell
root@generic_x86:/ # su
root@generic_x86:/ # mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
```

And then I get this...

```
mount: Read-only file system
```

Any ideas how I can make the system folder writeable?